# How to search for substring in bash script output string? If I searching in string directly it is working, but issue when searching in command output

Tags: bash, macos, shell, multipass

How to search for substring in bash script output? If I searching in string directly it is working, but issue when searching in command output.

```
variable="ping: test.com: Name or service not known"

if [[ "$variable" =~ "not" ]]  
then
    echo "Failed"
else
    echo "Success"
fi
```

This one is working.

But I am trying to do this:

```
variable=$(multipass exec genesis -- ping -c 1 test.com)

if [[ "$variable" =~ "not" ]]  
then
    echo "Failed"
else
    echo "Success"
fi
```

But like this is not working...

Output in termninal:

```
$ sh test3.sh
ping: test.com: Name or service not known
Success
```

I am expecting to get Failed...

I guess I need somehow handle ping output in variable in different way?

Comment: in my system `ping` sends the error message to stderr; assuming `multipass` is not modifying this behavior, try redirecting stderr to stdout (`2>&1`), ie: `variable=$(multipass exec genesis -- ping -c 1 test.com 2>&1)`

Comment: fwiw, the output shows the `ping` error is being sent to the terminal as opposed to being captured by the variable assignment (`variable=$( ...)`); adding `2>&1` on the end of the `multipass/ping` command should be sufficient to insure the variable assignment also captures anything send to stderr

Answer (score 1):

Why parsing the output?
There could be many other errors you won't catch.
Do this instead.

```
#! /bin/bash

if multipass exec genesis -- ping -c 1 test.com; then
    echo "Success"
else
    echo "Failed"
fi
```